# How to display all Big Commerce API data on stencil localhost

Tags: bigcommerce, bigcommerce-checkout-sdk

I was wondering how I could see the API data, if possible coming from my BigCommerce store.
I want to see what data I can utilize and customize before diving into customizations.
Since I don't have access to the back-end, it's hard to just guess the format of data coming in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually add `?debug=bar` to the end of the url. Of course if you're on a specific page replace the ? with an & since this is a query parameter.

This actually shows the JSON data coming in at the bottom of the page and is allowed to be used with the handlebars template Big Commerce uses.

Comment: This is good, but I prefer `?debug=context` inside of Firefox, because it gives you the full, pretty-printed JSON of all the data available to the page